# Using pointer to date (DATE * pValnDate) in ctypes

Tags: python, date, pointers, ctypes

I am trying to access a function in a COM DLL from python and OLE/COM Object Viewer + combrowse.py both suggest that a few of the inputs are pointers to a date variable:

From OLE/COM Object Viewer

```
// Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
// 
// typelib filename: ABC_Library.dll


    interface _clsABC_Library : IDispatch {
        [id(0x68030001), propget]
        HRESULT ABC_Value(
                        [in, out] DATE* PdateStartDate, 
                        [in, out] DATE* PdateEndDate 
... etc etc.
```

From combrowse.py:

```
...

 Argument = 'Pointer Date (Flags=3)'

...
```

I do not see an equivalent in ctypes. Any suggestions as to what DATE * means and how to set up the correct input from the python side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From googling `COM DATE`, I see [DATE Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/date-type?view=msvc-160):

> The DATE type is implemented using an 8-byte floating-point number. Days are represented by whole number increments starting with 30 December 1899, midnight as time zero. Hour values are expressed as the absolute value of the fractional part of the number.

So `DATE` could be represented in `ctypes` as `c_double` and `DATE*` would be `POINTER(c_double)`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Although this is almost certainly the correct answer, I am still getting a "nan" reply from the DLL. There must be something else that I am not getting right. There are far more variables that I've listed above and somewhere one of those must be incorrect.

Really appreciate your assistance!